# Adding spaces to a piped concatenation

Tags: sql

How do I change my select statement so that the following will return spaces between the concatenated columns?

The current query is similar to:

```
    SELECT
      address_line1 || address_line2 || address_line3 || address_line4 || city || state || county || province || country || zip as address
    FROM
      table
```

Many thanks

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? In Postgres you could simplify this to `concat_ws(' ', address_line1, address_line2, address_line3, ....)`

Answer (score 1):

Just add space characters in between the fields:

```
SELECT
    address_line1 || ' ' || address_line2 || ' ' || address_line3 || ' ' ||
        address_line4  || ' ' || city || ' ' || state || ' ' || county || ' ' ||
        province || ' ' || country || ' ' || zip AS address
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks